# Error: local variable a is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final

Tags: java

```
class Outer
{
    void m1()
    {
        int a=12;
        class Inner
        {
            void show()
            {
                System.out.println(a);
            }
        }
        new Inner().show();
    }

}
```

Here when i am compiling this code then i am getting error that is  local variable a is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final. but here  "int a"  is a local variable so why we need to declare as final for accessing in inner class .

Comment: @duffymo I think he wants to know **why** it's `final`, instead of just being a robot and doing what the compiler says...

Answer (score 4):

A local variable needs to be declared `final` if it's used in an inner class.  For a local variable to be used in such an inner class, Java behind the scenes takes a copy of the local variable and makes it into an implicit instance variable so the inner class can access it.  Because it's a copy, the copy could be wrong if the value changes.  So the compiler forces you to make it `final`.

Note that in Java 8, this would compile, because `a` is "effectively final" -- not declared `final`, but never changed once initialized.

[Section 8.1.3 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) states:

> Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in an inner class must either be declared final or be effectively final (§4.12.4), or a compile-time error occurs where the use is attempted.

[Section 4.12.4 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) states:

> A local variable or a method, constructor, lambda, or exception parameter is effectively final if it is not declared final but it never occurs as the left hand operand of an assignment operator (§15.26) or as the operand of a prefix or postfix increment or decrement operator (§15.14, §15.15).
>
> In addition, a local variable whose declaration lacks an initializer is effectively final if all of the following are true:
>
> - It is not declared final.
> - Whenever it occurs as the left-hand operand of an assignment operator, it is definitely unassigned and not definitely assigned before the assignment; that is, it is definitely unassigned and not definitely assigned after the right-hand operand of the assignment (§16 (Definite Assignment)).
> - It never occurs as the operand of a prefix or postfix increment or decrement operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily work around this by declaring your final variable as an array:

```
final int x[] = {2};
```

then from within your inner class, set the array value (example with method call returning a value):

```
x[0] = methodcall();
```

or (example with just setting the value to 10):

```
x[0] = 10;
```