# How can I prevent GPS from updating?

Tags: android, gps, locationlistener

When compiling the following code, I got compilation error:

```
Error:(154, 47) error: local variable locationListener is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
```

On the following line in `locationListener`:

```
getDistance(locationA,locationListener );
                    lm.removeUpdates(locationListener);
```

How can I prevent GPS from updating?

```
 locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
                Location net_loc, gps_loc;
                net_loc = location;
                while (net_loc != null) {
                    showCurrentLocation(net_loc);
                    Location locationA = new Location("A");
                    locationA.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
                    locationA.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
                    getDistance(locationA,locationListener );
                    lm.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                }
```

Comment: Either declare `locationListener` `final` where you have it, or move its declaration to the class scope.

Comment: i do this but it is never stop gps update

Comment: [You haven't search before asking](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+%22is+accessed+from+within+inner+class%3B+needs+to+be+declared%22+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1) 28 results with answers so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: local variable a is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429992/error-local-variable-a-is-accessed-from-within-inner-class-needs-to-be-declare)

Answer (score 0):

Try it with

```
lm.removeUpdates(this);
```

instead of

```
lm.removeUpdates(locationListener);
```

Also one point to remember that once enter the while loop in your code it runs continuously until the `net_loc==null`, so `lm.removeUpdates(locationListener)` calls every time.